# How to save documents in Office software?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, adobe-illustrator, save-as

A long time ago, to save an office document (Acrobat, Illustrator, Word, Excel...) I just had to hit  and choose the folder where I wanted to store it. The operating system was smart enough to suggest the last destination I used which was quite convenient.

Nowadays everything is much more complicated, and much slower. To save a Word document in a particular folder I have to hit  then use the `More save options` button, then use the `Browse` button, then navigate to the folder, then save...

Is there a way to just get rid of all this complexity and have the default save dialogue in every programs?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try changing Microsoft Office default save location via application settings.**

```
Note: You will need to do this for all Office Applications individually.
```

From : [How-to-change-the-default-save-location-to-a-custom-path-in-Office](https://support.centrestack.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034998913-How-to-change-the-default-save-location-to-a-custom-path-in-Office-365-2016)

> Step 1: Open the Office application where you want to change the
> default save location and click on Options.
>
> Step 2: Switch to the Save tab. In the Save documents section, select
> the check box next to the 'Save to Computer by default' option. Under
> that option there is an input field where you can enter the default
> path of your choice. You can also set a new default location by
> clicking the Browse button to choose a location.
>
> Once you have chosen your new default save location, click the OK
> button to save your changes.
>
> Now, when you create a new document and try to save it by clicking the
> Save button or by using the Ctrl + S key combination your document
> should save to the new location you specified.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue, and not yet find a solution for that.

However if instead of "save" you click "save as" you'll get immediately the traditional save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To get the traditional Save windows, you may go to File > Options > Save > Under the part of Save documents, check the box of "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files with keyboard shortcuts".

[image]

Then when you click the Save icon on Quick Access Toolbar, the traditional windows would prompted, but it won't suggest the last destination you used, it would show the default save location you set.